# R error when subsetting dataframe: "Error in ==: comparison of these types is not implemented"

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have some code which results in an error when I try to subset my dataframe.

The error occurs when I call for the makePopupPlot() function. R apparently doesn't like the data types I'm trying to compare inside the subset() function. I'm very confused, as the code worked perfectly yesterday and I didn't change anything.
The error does not occur when I manually run the makePopupPlot() function line-by-line. That means the error is most likely the result of using `df$WK_NAAM[i]` as input for the makePopupPlot() function.

The full error message as well as a reproducable example are provided below. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6941
Warning in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
Warning: Error in ==: comparison of these types is not implemented
  60: eval
  59: eval
  58: subset.data.frame
  55: makePopupPlot [#8]
  54: FUN [#29]
  53: lapply
  52: server [#28]
Error in plotData["WK_NAAM"] == clickedArea : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
```

**Reproducable example:**

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


set.seed(1)

# Let's use this municipality in the example
inputMunicipality = "Landgraaf"

# Download municipality geometry
df <-st_read(URLencode(sprintf("https://geo.leefbaarometer.nl/leefbaarometer/wfs?version=1.0.0&cql_filter=gemeente=%s%s%s&request=GetFeature&typeName=leefbaarometer:wijken_2018&srsName=epsg:4326&outputFormat=json",
                               "'", inputMunicipality, "'")))[c("WK_NAAM", "WK_CODE")]
# Add some fake scores
df$environmentScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$facilitiesScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$housingScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$safetyScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)


# Define dashboard UI 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing reactive popup on click event!"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(leafletOutput("myMap")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Function for generation a popup based on the area clicked by the user
  makePopupPlot <- function (clickedArea, df) {
    # prepare the df for ggplot
    noGeom <- st_drop_geometry(df)
    plotData <- noGeom[c("WK_NAAM", "environmentScore", "facilitiesScore","housingScore", "safetyScore")]
    plotDataSubset <- subset(plotData, plotData['WK_NAAM'] == clickedArea) 
    plotDataMelt = melt(plotDataSubset, id.vars = "WK_NAAM")
    
    popupPlot <- ggplot(data = plotDataMelt,  aes(x = variable, y = value, fill=value)) + 
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.9) +
      scale_fill_steps2(
        low = "#ff0000",
        mid = "#fff2cc",
        high = "#70ad47",
        midpoint = 5) +
      coord_flip() +
      ggtitle(paste0("Score overview in ", clickedArea)) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.5,0,0), "cm"), plot.title = element_text(size = 10))
    
    return (popupPlot)
  }
  
  # popup plot list
  p <- as.list(NULL)
  p <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    p[[i]] <- makePopupPlot(df$WK_NAAM[i], df)
  })
  
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$nlmaps.grijs) %>%
      addPolygons(data = df, popup = popupGraph(p, type = "svg")) 
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: With `subset`, do not bracket, `[...]` on same data frame. Simply refeeence column by name: `subset(plotData, WK_NAAM == clickedArea)`

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor issue here. Either wrap your column in double squared brackets or rather, the proper `subset()` style, just call the variable name unquotet:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


set.seed(1)

# Let's use this municipality in the example
inputMunicipality = "Landgraaf"

# Download municipality geometry
df <-st_read(URLencode(sprintf("https://geo.leefbaarometer.nl/leefbaarometer/wfs?version=1.0.0&cql_filter=gemeente=%s%s%s&request=GetFeature&typeName=leefbaarometer:wijken_2018&srsName=epsg:4326&outputFormat=json",
                               "'", inputMunicipality, "'")))[c("WK_NAAM", "WK_CODE")]
# Add some fake scores
df$environmentScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$facilitiesScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$housingScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$safetyScore <- sample(10, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)


# Define dashboard UI 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing reactive popup on click event!"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(leafletOutput("myMap")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Function for generation a popup based on the area clicked by the user
  makePopupPlot <- function (clickedArea, df) {
    # prepare the df for ggplot
    noGeom <- st_drop_geometry(df)
    plotData <- noGeom[c("WK_NAAM", "environmentScore", "facilitiesScore","housingScore", "safetyScore")]
    plotDataSubset <- subset(plotData, WK_NAAM == clickedArea) 
    plotDataMelt = melt(plotDataSubset, id.vars = "WK_NAAM")
    
    popupPlot <- ggplot(data = plotDataMelt,  aes(x = variable, y = value, fill=value)) + 
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.9) +
      scale_fill_steps2(
        low = "#ff0000",
        mid = "#fff2cc",
        high = "#70ad47",
        midpoint = 5) +
      coord_flip() +
      ggtitle(paste0("Score overview in ", clickedArea)) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.5,0,0), "cm"), plot.title = element_text(size = 10))
    
    return (popupPlot)
  }
  
  # popup plot list
  p <- as.list(NULL)
  p <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    p[[i]] <- makePopupPlot(df$WK_NAAM[i], df)
  })
  
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$nlmaps.grijs) %>%
      addPolygons(data = df, popup = popupGraph(p, type = "svg")) 
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```